# Can't install Pinnacle Studios 14 on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, wine

I'm trying to install Pinnacle Studio HD version 14 on my laptop, and I've already downloaded Wine and when I insert the installation CD, I can run the exe file. However, once that's all done with, nothing happens and it's like I haven't even downloaded it and I have to do it again. And again, but nothing happens still. Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The [Wine status for Pinnacle Studio 14 is "Garbage"](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19523). This usually means that no matter how much you're willing to battle, this is just never going to work under Wine.

You likely to have more luck under something like Virtualbox (with a virtualised install of Windows) but you might just do well to find an alternative application.

Comment: Okay thanks for the good (but sad) answer! I have another question then. What capture cards will co-operate with Ubuntu?

Comment: Lots of capture cards (Pinnacle ones included) present themselves as Video4Linux devices so it might be the case that it already just works. Without knowing what you have it's impossible for me to say if it'll work but try using it in VLC (it has a capture playback function). If that works you should be able to record through it.